# Convert complex Objective-C macros to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've used a library named [LinqToObjectiveC](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC) in my project and now I want to use it in swift files. this library uses complex objective-C macros which are not accessible in swift. I want to know how can I convert for example this macro to swift:

`#define LINQKey(__key) (^id(id item){return [item valueForKey:@#__key];})`

Comment: This is not complex at all, no need to use macros where you could use a simple function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's explain what that macro is doing.

It takes an argument called `__key`, stringifies it (`@` and `#`) and returns a closure (block) that will take an object as an parameter and returns the result of `item.valueForKey(key)`.

We can't convert stringification to Swift, however, that's something that shouldn't be used even in Obj-C. Why should we have `LINQKey(myKey)` when we can have `LINQKey(@"myKey")`?

As a simple function that returns a closure:

```
func LINQKey(key: String) -> (AnyObject! -> AnyObject!) {
    return { (item: AnyObject!) in
        return item.valueForKey(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, the author has used stringification because he wanted the user to pass object properties instead of arbitrary strings. your conversion is not working. it complains can not convert to expected argument type LINQSelector! would you mind to test?

Comment: `LINQSelector` is just a `typedef`, I have updated the optionals to be `!` which should fix your problem. It will be very annoying to use such library in Swift though. It should get a complete Swift rewrite.

Comment: how can I convert this one: `#define LINQSel(__key) (^id(id item){return [item __key];})` here __key is not string!

Comment: @HashemAboonajmi That's a method call. You are trying to convert very unsafe operations into a very safe language. In this case `__key` would have to be done with `#selector(__key)` and then you would have to use `performSelector`. I would really advice to drop Linq in Swift altogether. Just use Swift directly. You can write all the functional patterns in Swift directly, Linq is just making it too complicated.